# Как задать таймаут в HttpURLConnection для андроид?

Tags: java, android, http

Года 2-3 назад этот код работал, а потом вышли обновления и перестало.
Код получает строку с сервера. Всё работает.
А когда отправляю запрос на несуществующий адрес (просто для имитации недоступности), то прогресс бар крутит до упора, секунд 10-15.
Как прервать по таймауту? Гуглил, но все ответы ведут на аналогичный код и таймаут не работает.

**Java:**

```
private void GetDataFromServer(String url) {
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    final String[] answer = {"0"};
        new AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                URL url;
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
                try {
                    url = new URL(params[0]);
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(1000);                // таймаут
                    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(1000);
                    urlConnection.connect();
                    int ResponseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                    if (ResponseCode == 200){
                        InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        String bfr_st;
                        while ((bfr_st = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(bfr_st);
                        }
                        answer[0] = sb.toString();
                        is.close();
                        br.close();
                    }
                    else {
                        return "error";
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return "000";
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return "000";
                }
                return answer[0];
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String answer) {
                onComplete(answer);
            }
        }.execute(url);
}
```

**Xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Вот эта статья многое обьясняет: http://thushw.blogspot.com/2010/10/java-urlconnection-provides-no-fail.html

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, это статья Monday, October 11, 2010. Тогда всё работало.

Comment: `HttpURLConnection` с тех пор не изменился, на Андроид он забыт и заброшен. Переписывайте старый код на `OkHttp`.

Comment: И от `AsyncTask` заодно избавитесь.